# parentNode is null when walking up the DOM-tree from e.currentTarget in React

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

We are using react and have code similar to this:

```
const isDescendant = (predicateFn, child) => {
  let node = child.parentNode;

  while (node !== null) {
    if (predicateFn(node)) return true;
    node = node.parentNode;
  }

  return false;
}

componentDidMount() {
  const nodeIsModal = () => // ...

  const onBodyClick = (e) => {
    if (isDescendant(nodeIsModal, e.currentTarget)) {
      this.tryToClose();
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener('click', onBodyClick);
}
```

This seems to work but when we click **some** elements in the DOM and `isDescendant` starts walking up the DOM-tree from `e.currentTarget` it suddenly stops because `node.parentNode` returns `null`. The thing is that when clicking "inspect element" we clearly see that the node is in the middle of the DOM-tree and obviously has a parent node. It looks like the node (or it's ancestors) returned from `e.currentTarget` are somehow detached from the real DOM-tree.

Is react doing something here that gives this behaviour or are we tricking ourselves up some other how?

Comment: looks like react issue

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved in next way `document.body.addEventListener('click', onBodyClick)`. I had the same issue but now it works fine for me.